# .Net 4.6.2 C# Long Path Handling - Ilegal Character exception thrown only in release build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.6.2, long-filenames

I switched my project to .Net 4.6.2 to avoid MAX_PATH problems. I've also read that prepending "\\?\" allows longer paths. I did so but have a strange problem now. When building with the debug config it is working while the release config build is throwing a "Illegal characters in path." exception when doing e.g. this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigManager.PluginPath);
```

There are no changes in between and the composed path is the same in both cases according to the debugger.

I have currently no clue what is going wrong because all projects are switched to 4.6.2 and afaik this is not configuration dependant. Or am I missing an option here ?

```
public string AppPathRoot {
    get {
        // INFO: using long path prefix to prevent problems with MAX_PATH constraint
        return string.Format("\\\\?\\{0}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
        //return Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
I meanwhile tried a very simple environment using a Console application to ensure having no sideeffects. Interestingly it is now throwing in both cases, so no difference between release / debug. The path is existing. Im building this with VS2013 on Windows 7.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sPathL = "\\\\?\\C:\\temp";
        string sPath = "C:\\temp";

        // doesn't throw
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sPath);

        // throws
        DirectoryInfo di2 = new DirectoryInfo(sPathL);

    }
}
```

Edit2: 
It looks like that VS2013 behaves differently than VS2017. VS2017 throws no exceptions, VS2013 does...

Comment: What's the full path?

Comment: have you tried Path.Combine() rather than string.format() ?

Comment: @Trey: the problem is that the path is completely identical in both cases starting like this : \\?\C:\_Dev\... Only difference is Debug or Release build. Its maybe a configuration issue, but I don't know were to look. Targetframework is config a global project setting, so its in both cases 4.6.2

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: This probably doesn't change anything, because the path is identical when looking  at it in the debugger. but only the release build is failing.

Comment: i tried it on both release and debug with adding "\\\\?\\{0}" and without and it seem to work fine i also tried to exceed the possible path length in windows  and yet it works fine

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: I maybe should try that in a simple environment, because my project is fairly big to crosscheck. I'm using VS2013 which also maybe can cause this problem

Comment: Try just Application.ExecutablePath and see if it'll threw the same exception

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa : I tried, but no difference. But there must be something other very strange since the simple console app I tried is failing on both configs...

Comment: try this p/invoke 
`[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetModuleFileName(HandleRef hModule, StringBuilder buffer, int length);`

`StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(260);
            GetModuleFileName(new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero), stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
            Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);`

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: it's working, but what does it show ? I get the module name...

Comment: i Stepped into the built in code for property ExecutablePath and found that when the assembly is null they use that particular function to get the module name so after that you'll need to use some logic to get the desired path out of it

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa : but the problem is the prepended \\?\ , I get a completely valid application path in each case. Only this prefix breaks it sometimes as it looks right now

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: ok, it looks like VS2013 and VS2017 behave differently. VS2017 throws no exception in my console test, VS2013 does...

Comment: I've been testing only in VS2010 and it consider "\\?\" to be an illegal character